# handlebars dynamic table row

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am using Ember with Handlebars. I have a situation where I need to dynamically create new table rows after 3 iterations of an array.

```
<table>
{{#each items as |item itemIndex|}}
    {{#if (compare (mod itemIndex 3) '===' 0)}}<tr>{{/if}}
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>  
    {{#if (compare (mod itemIndex 3) '===' 2)}}</tr>{{/if}}
{{/each}}
</table>
```

For the sake of example, please assume that there will always be a factor of 3 in the items array. When I try to save this code, I'm getting a syntax error that there is no close  tag matching the open tag. How can I dynamically create the  and  without the syntax error?

I'm using ember CLI version 2.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the code snippet you have provided you will most likely encounter an error indicating `Error while processing route: index Unclosed element tr (on line 8). Error: Unclosed element tr (on line 8).` This is because `ember-template-compiler` does not know whether the rendering will result in a correct `HTML` page as a result of rendering. What if the `items` array is not divisible by 3; we will get an error in the runtime. In order to prevent that; `ember-template-compiler` throws an error indicating an unclosed `tr` tag.

So; what can be done to prevent this? You can create a computed property within your js file that simply returns the number of rows desired as follows:

```
rowCount: Ember.computed('items.length', function() {
    return this.get('items.length')/3;
})
```

afterwards you can simply make use of `range` helper provided by [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#range) and do the following within your template:

```
<table>
    {{#each (range 0 rowCount) as |rowIndex|}}
    <tr>
    {{#each (range 0 3) as |columnIndex|}}
        {{! `number` will go from 0 to 2}}
      <td>
        {{get (get-item-at-array-index items columnIndex rowIndex) 'id'}}
      </td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

The template code snippet provided above contains an helper named `get-item-at-array-index` which simply finds the relevant item at the desired index position and it should have a simple code as follows:

```
export function getItemAtArrayIndex(params/*, hash*/) {
  let array = params[0];
  let index = params[1];
  let rowIndex = params[2];

  return array[index+rowIndex*3];
}
```

I have prepared the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a33e0d881859e8a34303cac164abcb3e?openFiles=helpers.get-item-at-array-index.js%2C) for you that wraps up what I already explained above. By doing so; you will avoid the `Unclosed element tr` error you get; since the tags will be closing explicitly and template compiler will not complain.

Comment: Thanks, two loops with the range helper did it!

Comment: How would be this code if for example i need to link email with mailto instead of this text? or something like this?